# jQuery drop down menu show all links

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I wanted to create a menu like http://www.macheesmo.com/ (recipes) where all the links are shown (3 level deep).

This is waht I've come up so far - http://jsfiddle.net/MZxeA/

My problem is every time I leave the 3rd ul, the whole sub menu dissapears.

Another issue is that when I enter the second ul then go back to the first ul, the 3rd ul dissapears.

Another issue is with the selector, it doesn't work unless I remove the a.

The reason I wanted to include the a is to have an "on" style for the hover/trail.

```
$(function () {
    $(".main-nav ol li a").hover(function () {
        $(this).addClass("hover");
        $('ul', this).css({
            'visibility': 'visible'
        });
    }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass("hover");
        $('ul', this).css({
            'visibility': 'hidden'
        });
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Your jsfiddle example is not working, even after you select jQuery as the library

Comment: That's because there us no `ul` element in the context of the hovered `a` element. Also you haven't selected jQuery in the fiddle.

Comment: my bad, sorry new to jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MZxeA/1/

Comment: Do you realize that this type of menu is designed to work without JavaScript? Unless you're adding delays or transitions, there's no reason to use JS. This works, though the 3rd-level items are styled poorly: http://jsfiddle.net/MZxeA/3/

Comment: This is better, but the 3rd-level items will need to be off to the side. When they collapse the cursor is over nothing, so the menu collapses entirely. http://jsfiddle.net/MZxeA/5/

Comment: Here's one that's pretty close to working. Note the styles I've added at the top. I've also added {display: none} wherever {visibility: hidden} already existed. http://jsfiddle.net/MZxeA/7/

Answer (score 0):

what you do in jsfiddle came with some mistakes i'll try to fix it with you 1 by 1

1. first of all you need to include jquery file in your code. to write some code with jquery help. to include jquery file you can use local file of jquery and this code

> ```
> <script src="local/jquery.min.js" />
> ```

1. you need to make the position of sub menu absolute. and the li holder him to position:relative. is make the sub related to him father and the the top and left value put your submenu in true place like you want.
2. in visible option have some issues to use. for submenu's jquery give you e.g. the show() and hide() option. in this code you can see short and better code to do the work

> ```
> $(function () {
>     $(".main-nav ol li a").hover(function () {
>         $(this).addClass("hover");
>         $(this).next('ul').show();
>     }, function () {
>         $(this).removeClass("hover");
>         $(this).next('ul').hide();
>     });
> });
> ```

you can if you want also try replace the show() and hide() with fadeOut() and fadeIn() to make some transition.

in a glad to help

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments the way to do this is to leave the javascript out of it, just use CSS (like the example site you are trying to copy does).

Basically you have three nested lists, level 1-3, where only level 1 is visible by default. This is a toy example of how the styles work:

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Sub item1
        <ul>
          <li>Third level items go here</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Sub item without third level items..</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2, no submenu</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
/* Hide the submenu by default */
#menu > li > ul {
  display:none;
}

/* Show on parent hover */
#menu > li:hover > ul {
  display:block;
}
```

Now that is very basic HTML/CSS, only showing the show hide part of this exercise, but the rest is not really relevant to the question anyway.

If you, for whatever reason, really want to use jQuery for this you can remove the second style rule above and use this script to get the same effect:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#menu > li').hover(function(){
    $(this).children('ul').show();
  }, function(){
    $(this).children('ul').hide();
  });
});
```